# Cannot perform a differential backup for database "ABC", because a current database backup does not exist

Tags: sql-server, backup

Im trying to take differential back up on sql 2005 server with SP4 (Workgroup Edition) but it gives me below error...

```
Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot perform a differential backup for database "ABC", because a current database backup does not exist. 
Perform a full database backup by reissuing BACKUP DATABASE, omitting the WITH DIFFERENTIAL option. 
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Fullbackup exists but its still giving above message. I found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921106) but it seems this is applicable for sql server 2005 with no service pack.

I got below error when I tried to install above hotfix.

> This update requires service pack 0. The service pack for product instance MSSQLSERVER is 4.Download the update for service pack 4.

Answer (score 0):

First try a full backup and then the differential backup. It is possible that your backup chain to the existing full backup is somehow broken.